# React-Router Not Returning Nested Route: Warning: [react-router] Location "//profile" did not match any routes

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router

I'm using React-Router v. 2.4.0 and trying to render a nested route when the user navigates to the the path `#/?_k=mftgqo/profile`.  However, I am receiving the following error message in the browser:

`Warning: [react-router] Location "//profile" did not match any routes`

**App.js file:**

```
var React = require('react');
var ReactDOM = require('react-dom');
var Router = require('react-router').Router;
var hashHistory = require('react-router').hashHistory;
var routes = require('./routes');

ReactDOM.render(
  <Router history={hashHistory}>{routes}</Router>,
  document.getElementById('app')
)
```

***routes.js file***

```
var React = require('react');
var Main = require('./Main');
var Home = require('./Home');
var Profile = require('./Profile');
var Router = require('react-router');
var Route = Router.Route;
var IndexRoute = Router.IndexRoute;

module.exports = (
  <Route path='/' component={Main}>
    <Route path='profile' component={Profile} />
    <IndexRoute component={Home} />
  </Route>
);
```

The index route is rendering properly but not the profile route.  Any thoughts on this?

Comment: Looks like you're on the wrong side of the route there, try testing at `localhost:.../#/profile`, with the '...' being whichever port you are on.

Comment: @BradColthurst:  Just edited the question - serving a static file for now in the browser with route `file://Users/mtaggart/project/public/index.html#/?_k=mftgqo/profile`

Comment: @BradColthurst:  When I open index.html in the browser, it is automatically defaulting to ``file://Users/mtaggart/project/public/index.html#/?_k=i2axpp`` for some reason. When I change the route to 'index.html/#/profile', I receive an error saying that the file is not found.

Comment: It's from hashHistory in the react-router, you can switch to browserHistory for the cleaner URL's. There is more about it in the docs: https://github.com/reactjs/react-router/blob/master/docs/guides/Histories.md

Comment: @BradColthurst:  Set up localhost environment and switched to browserHistory, as suggested, which worked. Thanks for your insight.  Not sure if the issue is specific to react-router version 2.0 when trying to use nested routes w/ hashHistory.

Comment: No problem, it's effectively just not accounting the `?_k` string, so your route was going from `index/?_k.../profile` to `index//profile`, which throws the error